# Set custom response in Spring interceptor

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, session, interceptor

Here is my interceptor method where i want to set custom response to tell the UI what happened

```
@Override
        public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler)
                throws Exception {
    HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
    if (session != null) 
         return true;
        else{
        response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_REQUEST_TIMEOUT)
        return false;
        }
    }
```

And in web.xml

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>408</error-code>
    <location>/error.html</location>
</error-page>
```

spring-servlet.xml

```
<mvc:interceptors>
        <mvc:interceptor>
            <mvc:mapping path="/**" />
            <mvc:exclude-mapping path="/login" />
            <bean class="com.example.CustomInterceptor" />
        </mvc:interceptor>
    </mvc:interceptors>
```

When the session is timed out its not sending any response after return false.
Even the below is not working

```
response.sendRedirect("http://localhost:8080/home");
```

Comment: How does you complete URL look like?

Answer (score 0):

You can try very simple thing. Change your `mvc:interceptros` structure to

```
<mvc:interceptors>
     <bean class="com.example.CustomInterceptor" />
</mvc:interceptors>
```

This essentially mean apply the interceptor to all applicable requests. I will come in a moment to why I say applicable in a moment. If above works then the issue is with your mapping.

Now as you know interceptors are configured at the level of `HandlerMapping` and it will be `RequestMappingHandlerMapping` (Spring 3.1+ with `mvc:annotation-driven`) or `DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping` in your case.

Now as you have use `<mvc:mapping path="/**" />` will map to all requests (including subpaths) as long as they are **valid mappings**. So lets say you have controller

```
@RequestMapping(value="/home", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String welcome() {
    return "welcome";
}
```

you cannot hit `http://localhost:8080/yourProjectName/home/test` and expect it to hit the interceptor. So you have to hit `http://localhost:8080/yourProjectName/home` as that is a valid HandlerMapping.

As to to response first debug if your interceptor is getting hit for any requests. If it does work then

```
response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_REQUEST_TIMEOUT);
```

should redirect you to `error.html` as you have used

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>408</error-code>
    <location>/error.html</location>
</error-page>
```